# What to subclass from UITableView

Tags: uitableview, datasource, subclass

Let's say I have 10 tableViews that all need to have the first cell's background , in all sections , color set to red.

In order not to do that manually for all the 10 table views I'm thinking that I should subclass UITableView.

My question would be: what should I overwrite from UITableView?

Or should I subclass UITableViewCell and all cells inherit from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass UITableViewCell and then you will have to somehow give the section&row to the cell so that it knows to set the background.

However, you can also subclass UITableView. Below is a solution if you choose to subclass UITableView, but in the end it's your decision.

The only way I can think of right now is to somehow catch all requests to the tableView data source so that you can then manipulate the results.

You can do it like this:

- Subclass UITableView, let's call it MyUITableView like this:
- Add a member variable `id<UITableViewDataSource> myDataSource`, and also a property for this variable with IBOutlet set to it. Then in Interface Builder, you should connect the table view using this property instead of the standard uitableview datasource property.
- Somewhere in the `init` or `loadView`, write `self.dataSource = self`. The idea is to catch all requests (expecially `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) so that you can manipulate the actual results.
- In your subclass, implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol, and just forward all calls to the myDataSource object.
- The only exception is in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation where after you get the result from myDataSource, you can change the background color if a specific condition is  met. See an example code below

@interface MyUITableView : UITableView  {
    id<UITableViewDataSource> myDataSource;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet id<UITableViewDataSource> myDataSource;

@end

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get the result from the actual data source
    UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
    if (myDataSource)
        cell = [myDataSource tableView:self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // If you condition is met, then just modify the cell in some way
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

And this is pretty much all you need. I don't know if I was clear enough, but if you have any questions don't hesitate.

Comment: Thanks! This works.Nicely done. I was trying to overWrite setDataSource (to catch the cellForRowAtIndexPath method)in my custom tableView, but i was having problems setting the cell's in their position. But you solution is way more elegant.